# While using %sql with Python, how to remove the quotes of a variable passing from python to %sql?

Tags: python, postgresql, ipython

I am trying to run a for loop in python which iterate all table names in postgresql database, and return the variable counts for each table. However if I pass a variable using %sql with :, the variable would come with a quotes and made the table name invalid. eg:

```
tablename = 'film'
film_count = %sql select count(*) from :tablename
```

what I want to pass with %sql is

```
film_count = %sql select count(*) from film
```

However it became

```
film_count = %sql select count(*) from 'film'
```

Then system return syntax error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "'film'"
LINE 1: select count(*) from 'film'
                             ^
```

Could anyone help me to understand how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the examples in https://pypi.org/project/ipython-sql/ , `:` will enclose variables with quotes.

Use `$` or `{}` instead

Comment: Thank you! {} works like a charm. The reference document is very helpful too.